# Moodle 3.4 installation on Centos 7

Tags: apache, centos7, moodle, php-7

Installing a test Moodle (3.4.1) using the instructions on Moodle site but only got blank page when accessing it. I put the moodle installation on /var/www/html/moodle. The install.php script returns with success.

I am using PHP 7.0 on the ius repository.

httpd error log has these entries:
[Thu Jan 18 10:45:24.626059 2018] [:error] [pid 29857] [client ::1:41946] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

[Thu Jan 18 10:21:39.114019 2018] [:error] [pid 28769] [client ::1:41930] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/moodle/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

I have tried to chmod to 755 and still the same problem. 
Am I missing some php libraries?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I did something wrong during the first install. Redid a clean install and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to give all the rights

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/moodle
```